# Jquery accessibility keycode is not working

Tags: jquery, accessibility

For the sake of accessibility practice I am doing keycode jquery function for removing 'li' tag on enter key.  But which is not working.  I dont know why. I followed good code practice and referred lot of code models.  Everyone says the same way of approach I followed.  Below is the code sample...

Jquery code:

```
$('.textCapDisplay .removeTag').keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {                    
                $(this).closest('li').remove();                  
            }
        });
```

HTML constructor which are loading dynamically...

```
<ul class="tCDCont">
    <li class="added segoe-ui-symbol"><span class="textCont"> dasfa</span><span tabindex="0" class="removeTag"></span></li>
    <li class="added segoe-ui-symbol"><span class="textCont"> sfas</span><span tabindex="0" class="removeTag"></span></li>
    <li class="added segoe-ui-symbol"><span class="textCont"> fasf</span><span tabindex="0" class="removeTag"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help me out to get this code workable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to markup you've posted here, Try this selector:

```
$('.tCDCont .removeTag').keydown(function (e) {
```

Instead of

```
$('.textCapDisplay .removeTag').keydown(function (e) {
```

### [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1ws7ot7x/)

If li's are generated dynamically, you need [event delegation with `.on()`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document.body).on("keydown", ".tCDCont .removeTag", function (e) {
```

### [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1ws7ot7x/2/)

*Note:* To fire keydown event those icons should be focused.

Comment: Yes... this is blender mistake I made.  Thanks for your update.  But still it is not working properly.  It is not responding.  I suspect that 'li's are dynamically adding.

Comment: @user3667940 If li's are dynamically adding i think you need event delegation for the same, you should mention that part in your question too!

Comment: Great... this one is working... Thanks for your timely help dude.